# MS SSAS - Need to return a measure in a calculated member based on a tuple set and a max ofunderlying ID

Tags: ssas, mdx

I require some more advanced MDX knowledge than mine.

I need to get the RepoRate_MAX for repo products, at book and instrument level, but also looking at the Java code I'm replacing that code always uses the max MurexId.

How can I perform the below (I've placed MAX in here on the dimension but this is wrong) and I need the combo of the dimensions and also the MAX MurexId:

```
[Measures].[RepoRate_VAL] = (([Deal].[ProductType].&[REPO],[Deal].[Book],[Deal].[Instrument],MAX([Deal].[MurexId])),[Measures].[RepoRate_MAX])
```

I'm sure it's a simple one but my mind is part way between the Java OO and MDX worlds currently haha :D

Thanks

Leigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some experimenting I found out about the TAIL and Item MDX functions.

I think at one point I did get it working, but didn't make a note of what did work. I was playing around with this and variants of it..but most versions ended up in unusable query times:

```
[Measures].[RepoRate_VAL] = (([Deal].[ProductType].&[REPO],[Deal].[Book],[Deal].[Instrument],TAIL(EXISTING([Deal].[MurexId].[MurexId])).Item(0)),[Measures].[RepoRate_MAX])
```

So I then decided to push the RepoRate calculation back to the SQL data preparation script. Cleaner/smoother data is always better and then to have simple calculated members.

I used SQL to determine the RepoRate from tradelevel with MAX(MurexId) and GROUP BY on Book, Instrument to then update my main fact table to ensure that the correct RepoRate was set at Book, Instrument level.

Thus the calculated member is then:

```
[Measures].[RepoRate_VAL] = (([Deal].[Book],[Deal].[Instrument]),[Measures].[RepoRate_MAX])
```

Fast data prep and a fast calculated member on the Excel/Pivot/UI layer.